# how do i animate the following GridView properly or any other way?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

i'm new to flutter. 
Trying to make a simple game. was stuck at animation part , i have done somehow but not perfect. any help will b appreciated .

target: the following gif is the same game that i have implemented in kotlin but now i'm trying in flutter

[image: kotlin Jerry Game]

Code:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Jerry Game"),
      ),
      body: MyGameBody(),
    );
  }
}

class MyGameBody extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          MyScoreBoard(),
          ImageGrid(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

//----------------------------------------------------------------ImageGrid --

```
class ImageGrid extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImageGridState createState() => _ImageGridState();
}

class _ImageGridState extends State<ImageGrid> {
  Image image = Image.asset("images/jerry.png");
  List<Widget> fixedImageList;
  var random = new Random();
  var index;
  Timer timer;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //  int gridLength = stringGridState.length;

    Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 1000), (Timer t) {
      fixedImageList = new List.generate(9, (index) => Container());

      index = random.nextInt(9 - 0);
      fixedImageList[index] = image;
      setState(() {});
    });

    return Container(
      color: Colors.greenAccent,
      child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 1.0,
          child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              color: Colors.green,
              child: GridView(
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 3),
                  children: fixedImageList))),
    );
  }
}
```

By above flutter code i get this which is not perfect:

[image: Flutter Jerry Game]